# Making one item float to the right

Tags: html, css

Although this may seem like a very dumb question, I have been having trouble to make one of the items stick to the right. So far I have a couple items and I want the 'Logout' button to stick to the right side.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout {
  margin-left: -90%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <div class="logout">
          <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

The ghetto-like solution I thought would work was to make a div called 'logout' and then add a `float: right;` to `.logout` in the main.css file. This, in fact, didn't work and just made things worse.

Comment: remove the div and apply float to the last li

Comment: you will also need to remove the float from `nav`

Comment: You HTML is also **invalid**. A `ul` may only have `li ` as children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `nav` width and add the `float:right;`

Like that :

```
nav {
  float: left;
  width:100%
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1drvnfn/)

Answer (score 0):

You just had some mistakes in your css and html codes. Try this code to get the result you desired.

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  left: 0;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Floated elements need to be before the elements that will wrap around them. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the `margin-left: -90%` on `.logout`; that's what was interfering when you tried adding `float`. Remove it.  There's no need to wrap the element in a `div`, you can just put the classname directly on the `li`.    Lastly, the `float:left` on `nav` is collapsing the width of the nav element; you can remove that and it will automatically fill the window width (adding `width: 100%` would be harmless but redundant.)

(You'll still need to add some media queries to handle the case where there isn't enough room for all the elements to fit on one line, but that wasn't the question, and there are several different ways it could be solved, so I won't address it here)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Reason for downvote?  I'm open to suggestion for improvement to the answer!

Comment: I didn't downvote, I think you did well on the explanation, although you didn't answer the question, your "Logout" is floated right, but the problem was that he wanted "Logout" to stick to the right side, which is achieved by adding   `width: 100%;` to the `nav` element - look at @Core972's answer. Also you could have shown how you would handle the media query problem when you already adressed it.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that, @MarcHjorthLaustsen -- I forgot to check larger screen sizes, will correct the answer.

Comment: No problem, keep it up :)